# Stroke a path from thick to thin

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, brush, pen-tool

I manage to stroke a path so that the brush goes thin -> thick -> thin along a path. Thing is though that I want the stroke to go thick -> thin, meaning I want the stroke to start at its thickest and then go thinner and thinner along the path.

I can't seem to figure this out using the Brush shape dynamics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to brush panel, Select Shape Dynamics, Select Fade as the Control type of Size Jitter.By increasing the length of the Fade you can control the how quickly it transitions from thickest to thinnest point. Having this approximate the length of the line you are stroking will likely yield best results. Additionally the Minimum Diameter can be set to ensure that the line never completely fades out and disappears.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! And great with the screen shot showing all the settings, that really helped!

Answer (score 4):

To get higher control you can use the `Pen Pressure` option for the `Shape Dynamic` in the **Brush panel**, if you have pen tablet installed.

If not, the only option is to adjust the `Jitter` for the `Shape Dynamic` in the **Brush Panel**, and set it to `Fade`.

Answer (score 0):

Set brush size really small, draw a straight and draw over one half of the line.

Comment: This is a really old question, besides your suggestion will produce an uneven line. Check the other answers.